# Android app including android lib including jar

Tags: android, jar, google-analytics

I have following projects configuration under eclipse :
- a projet generating an apklib, containing 99% of my code and resources
- 2 projects generating apks, including previous apklib (with maven dependency and referenced in 2 top default.properties files).
2 top projects can be ran from eclipse, on simulator or device, successfully. They can also be compiled and deployed through maven builds.

So far everything is fine.

Now i need to integrate Google Analytics in my project, so basically i have to include the .jar in the apklib project where resides my code. After trying every possible ways, i ended up with the maximal configuration :
The libGoogleAnalytics.jar is both

- defined as maven dependency on the three pom.xml
- also added physically in lib/ folders under each project, and added to eclise classpath.

When running with eclipse 'Run as' on emulator or device, it's ok.
When running with mvn clean install, then mvn android:deploy, it fails on device because GA classes are not found.

Any idea how to solve this configuration ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure Google Analytics is in your build path before the final step :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try just include the .jar into the libs of the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same type of problem, but not using maven.
I have read that compiler don't include external .jar from lib project to run project.

I have spend lot of time to try, without good result. Now I include the .jar in lib and run project.